# Return webservice results in text/html in the body instead of JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How can I return a result from a webservice as an HTML document with the result in the body instead of JSON in ASP.NET C#.

Using asmx and jQuery.

Comment: What are you using? ASMX web services, WCF, Web API, something else?

Comment: What kind of javascript libraries are you using?